# Line Integral of $e^{z}z^{-n})$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I was trying to evaluate the following line integral

$I$ = $\int_{|z|=1} e^{z}z^{-n} dz$

My approach  :let $|z|=1$ be a curve $\gamma$ 
I defined a function $f(z) = e^{z}z^{-(n-1)}$ so now $0 \notin \gamma$ and $0$ lies inside the curve so Local Cauchy's Integral formula can be applied at $f(0)$ 
thus

$f(0) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1} e^{z}z^{-n} dz = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1} \frac{e^z\times z^{-(n-1)}}{z-0} dz $

and $f(0) = 0$

Thus $I=0$

Is this fine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kobe's answer is just fine, but just to provide an other point of view, $f(z)=\frac{e^{z}}{z^n}$ is a meromorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$ with a pole of order $n$ in the origin, so by the residue theorem:

$$\int_{|z|=1}f(z)\,dz = 2\pi i\cdot\operatorname{Res}\left(f(z),z=0\right) \tag{1}$$
and since:
$$ e^{z} = \sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{z^m}{m!} \tag{2}$$
we just have:
$$ \operatorname{Res}\left(f(z),z=0\right) = \frac{1}{(n-1)!}.\tag{3}$$

Answer (score 2):

No it's incorrect. Certainly $0$ lies inside $\gamma$, but your function $f(z)$ is not analytic inside and on $\gamma$. Instead, let $f(z) = e^z$, and use the Cauchy differentiation formula to obtain

$$I = \frac{2\pi i}{(n-1)!} f^{(n-1)}(0) = \frac{2\pi i}{(n-1)!}.$$

Comment: Can you explain Cauchy's differentiation formula ?
I seem to not know it well.

Comment: @sammath [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Theorem) is the statement.